# loading some of the page content after page loads to increase page speed

Tags: html, performance, pagespeed

As number of my website visitors increased I bought a CDN service but I was surprised to see that my page load time has increased. today I chat with the CDN staff and they persuaded me (by reports) that the ads which are loaded from a third party website are slow and they make my website load slower.

I can not remove ads as they are paying for everything and I can not bear this speed either. I wanted to know if I load the ads after page loads, would it improve the results? or it still we be counted?

Comment: well I want to know if I use ajax will it increase the speed? won't it be counted measuring page load time? and where to use ajax to load ad content?

Comment: yes ajax will increase the speed, it will not be counted as it will not run at the time of loading and use ajax after body.onload

Comment: thanks. let me test it

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui It worked. if you add it as answer I'll accept it.